# Try to understand getIndexCurrent() function in ElasticSearch

Tags: elasticsearch

I'm new to ElasticSearch, and trying to understand what does [getIndexCurrent()](http://xbib.org/elasticsearch/1.5.1/apidocs/org/elasticsearch/index/indexing/IndexingStats.Stats.html#getIndexCurrent--) function mean. Based on this [ElasticSearch tutorial](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/_monitoring_individual_nodes.html?q=monitoring), it means the number of docs currently being indexed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's correct, `index_current` is the total number of docs currently being indexed. It is different than the `index_total` figure which is an increasing counter of how many indexing operations have taken place in that index.

In the below example, we see that the index currently contains 99 documents.

```
"indexing": {
      "index_total": 803441,
      "index_time_in_millis": 367654,
      "index_current": 99,
      "delete_total": 0,
      "delete_time_in_millis": 0,
      "delete_current": 0
},
```